# With PM2, how can I update / deploy the code if the git branch has been force pushed?

Tags: git, pm2

Starting with PM2 here.

Context:
While we don't allow *production* or *staging* branches history to be modified (to be force pushed), we do allow it for *dev* or *feature* branches so that the commits can be squashed before review and moved to production.

But PM2 is trying to pull and so fails in that case. Is it possible to have PM2 fetch remote and then overwrite instead of trying to pull and apply changes?

As a side note: a few platforms such as Netlify, or Heroku, allow code to be force pushed and deploy. I'd like to reproduce it with PM2.

Comment: Is it possible to use `pm2 deploy name_of_the_config.json setup` while adding `rm -rf /path/to/the/folder` in the post-deploy hook so it just kind of reinstall the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, there is no clean way to do this.
PM2 does not allow us to choose how to merge.

But there is a **work-around**: there is an undocumented **[pre-deploy hook](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4687)**.
And we can use it to fetch the code that has been force-pushed.

You can write your deployment config to fetch the update like this:

```
  some-deployment:
    ref: origin/dev
    repo: ...
    path: ...
    pre-deploy: "git fetch && git reset --hard origin/dev"
```

For more details and maybe push the pm2 developers to offer a clean solution, here is this [Github issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4390).